# SwiftUI Readonly binding

Tags: swift, swiftui

I am trying to create a SwiftUI view that has a @Binding bool to update it's internal state depending on the value. I want that bool value to be a `isEmpty` property of a String stored in a @ObservedObject.

I will explain my issue in a reduced example.

Let's start with a view model:

```swift
@MainActor
final class MainViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var magicString = ""

    init(magicString: String = "") {
        self.magicString = magicString
    }
}
```

Then the view that declares the initial binding, I do not want this view to own the data.

```swift
struct BoolView: View {
    @Binding var active: Bool
    
    var body: some View {
        HStack() {
            Image(systemName: active ? "checkmark.circle" : "xmark.circle")
                .foregroundStyle(active ? .green : .red)
            Text("Is magic happening?")
            Spacer()
        }
    }
}
```

Lastly I want to add this as a subview of "main view" that has the view model:

```swift
struct MainView: View {
    @ObservedObject var viewModel: MainViewModel
    var body: some View {
        BoolView(active: Binding<Bool>(get: { // This is what I do not like
            !viewModel.magicString.isEmpty
        }, set: { _, _ in
        }))
    }
}
```

While this works, I would like to avoid creating the new `Binding<Bool>`.
How can I pass `viewModel.magicString.isEmpty` to the `BoolView` active binding?
Maybe I should not be using @Binding property wrapper in `BoolView`?

Comment: Binding is by definition a Two way connection, a one way Binding is a fallacy. Just use let

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If it's read-only then it doesn't need to be a binding. The parent is already dependent on the observed object, so this will cause the body of the parent to be rebuilt when the observed object changes.

Just change the property inside `BoolView` to this:

```swift
    let active: Bool
```

and your `MainView` to this:

```swift
struct MainView: View {
    @ObservedObject var viewModel: MainViewModel
    var body: some View {
        BoolView(active: !viewModel.magicString.isEmpty)
    }
}
```